# Group by - Excel Power Query multiple rows into one

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have data I loaded to Power Query  - each Employee has mulitple rows and its looks like this:

empNum reason 1 reason 2 reason 3

3453    1         null    null

3453    null      1       null

3453    null      null    1

How can I transform the data to look like this?

empNum reason 1 reason 2 reason 3

3453    1        1        1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **EDIT**

You may try in this way as well, so, the steps are as follows:

• Select any cell of the source,

• From **Data Tab** --> Click From **Table/Range** (**Under Get & Transform Group**)

• Select the **First Column** i.e. `EmpNum` and right click `Unpivot Other Columns`,

• From **Home Tab** --> **Under Transform Group** --> Click `Group By`,

• **GroupBy EmpNum** --> **New Column Name** -> `Group` --> **Operation** --> `All Rows` --> Press **Ok**

• From **Add Custom Tab** --> Under **General Group** --> Click --> `Custom Column`

• **New Column Name** --> `Reason`

• **Custom Column Formula** -->

```
`Table.Column([Group],"Value")`
```

• Press **Ok**

• Then Extract The Values From The Reason Column By Pressing The **Dropdown and Click Extract Values**

• Select **Delimiter** as your choice ( `I took comma` )

• Once Extracted Goto **Home Tab** --> Select `Split Column by`,

• **By Delimiter** -> Delimiter is `Comma` should be at `Each Occurence of the delimiter` and press **Ok** (`Also Note in Advanced Options By Default it is Split into Columns`)

• Remove the column that not required and from **Home Tab** press `Close & Load Drop down`, from **Import Data** choose either `Existing sheet` or `New Sheet` and press Ok

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"EmpNum"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"EmpNum"}, {{"Group", each _, type table [EmpNum=number, Attribute=text, Value=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Reason", each Table.Column([Group],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Reason", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Reason", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Reason.1", "Reason.2", "Reason.3"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Group"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image: GROUP BY]

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery you can try

click select first column

right click ... unpivot other columns

click select attribute column, transform ... pivot column, use Values as values column, advanced options, dont aggregate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"empNum"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```